# how do we encrypt a media file with different keys at different time intervals

Tags: ios, encryption

Problem:
My problem is related to apple's mediafilesegmenter usage to encrypt the hls video file with key rotation.
I have a video file say 60minutes length and I want to change the key after say 3 minutes, 5 minutes, and 4minutes and 25secs, 7minutes etc.
The apple tool allows me to rotate keys, but only on a factor of my segment duration.
For example if my segment duration is 10secs, I can rotate the key say, 10X20, means after every 20 segments, keys will be changed, that's not sufficient in my case as I have to change on a random time.
I don't find a way to do this and I have no control over these time intervals which can be different for different videos and i get it as a input file.
Any suggestions/ideas on this regard is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question asked in the apple developer forum as well and I got a response and wanted to share here.

*there is no way to do this.  We can rotate the keys regularly based on time, but not based on what you'd like.

Our recommendation, however, is not to rotate keys as often; rotate them every few hours, and rotate the IVs every 50MBytes.

If you really have to rotate the keys (which we don't recommend), you can break the video up into "chapters", and put the chapters together in the playlist with discontinuities.*

Comment: Bumping on this. If we generate keys on a 2-hour interval, our servers would be flooded with keys in 2 years right? We also won't be able to delete them as the playlist would contain them.